# Apple SignIn invalid grant

Tags: ios, apple-sign-in

I have implemented login/signup using apple login in my website and everything is working fine. I have created a service id, created the key, configured the redirect uri and generated the client secret.

Now I'm trying to implement the login on my iOS application and validate the login through our backend using apple API. The login is working on iOS and we correctly receive the authorization code but I can't validate it using the apple API.

I'm using the exact same code for the website just changing the client id (I'm using the bundle id) and the client secret which I have regenerated with the bundle id. I always get the following response:

> { "error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "The code has expired
> or has been revoked." }

This is the sample code I'm using for validation:

```
    token_url = current_app.config.get('APPLE_OAUTH_URI') + '/token'

    body = {
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
        'code': code,
        'redirect_uri': current_app.config.get('APP_BASE_URL') + '/login/apple/callback',
        'client_secret': client_secret,
        'client_id': client_id
    }

    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }

    token_response = requests.post(
        token_url,
        headers=headers,
        data=body
    )
```

What am I missing?